# How do I create a RSS feed using excel?

Tags: excel, rss

I want to create an RSS feed using data in excel. 
Something like this

```
Product ID     Product Name     Product Price    Delivery Date
11111          Apple iphone        650              2-4 days
22222          Samsung Galaxy      600              5-6 days
```

How do i directly convert this data in excel into an RSS feed.

Comment: Do you want just the RSS XML as a file, or something served over the internet which is automatically updated?

Comment: I have an RSS reader in my website. I get data from others in the excel format. I need to convert this into an RSS feed and input that link in my site RSS reader. Hope i am clear

Comment: I don't know a great deal about RSS, but I thought it only really had a brief description of the article (or your data) and a link to said article. Are you sure RSS is what you want? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my website is a price comparison one and i get data from many vendors in excel format. since its a highly live website i need to link it with RSS. Can import XML into excel so thought is there a possibility to export excel to RSS..

Answer (score 2):

Below is a blog post about reporting worksheet changes via RSS.  It uses the MSXML2 library to generate the XML file and uses Dropbox as the web server.  Basically, you need to create an XML file and upload it to a web server.  The XML file creation you can get from the post, but the webserver part will be highly specific to your situation.

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/03/16/monitor-worksheet-changes-via-rss/

Comment: I am able to do it through VBA macros. http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/12/15/create_an_rss_feed_with_excel/This creates a local XML link.. How do i convert that into a public link for my website ? something like www.google.com/rss.xml

Comment: Name the file rss.xml and ftp it to your webserver.  To ftp in VBA, see here http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/01/29/ftp-via-vba/