# Can I upload a text file into HTML daily?

Tags: html, automation

How would I go about automatically 'pushing' a file that I make edits on, to a website daily?

I'm sure there are many method's, but what is something relatively simple?

Comment: I am creating an internal website to monitor tasks that I've completed so there is more visibility on my projects at work - but actually maintaining the site takes too long. I want to just push the excel and text documents automatically?

Comment: So you want to make something like a RSS feed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303970/how-do-i-create-a-rss-feed-using-excel

Answer (score 0):

A good way to automaticly synchronise an excel sheet would be to convert it to a Google Sheet and embed it in your website thereafter :

http://wcmshelp.ucsc.edu/advanced/google-docs.html

Then make sure that the sheet is set in readonly when displayed on your website.